# selecting worksheet with multiple workbooks open crahses

Tags: excel, vb.net

If I only create one workbook the following works fine

```
Dim oXl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim wb_main As Workbook
wb_main = oXl.Workbooks.Add
...add sheets and data to sheets
CType(wb_main.Worksheets(1), Worksheet).Select()
wb_main.SaveAs(Filename:=_files(0)._file_path.parentDir.parentDir & "out.xlsx")
```

But with two open, i get an error.  Interop errors are not alwasy straightforward to debug.

```
Dim oXl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim wb_main As Workbook
Dim wb_extended As Workbook
wb_main = oXl.Workbooks.Add
wb_extended = oXl.Workbooks.Add
...add sheets and data to sheets in both workbooks, no particular order
CType(wb_main.Worksheets(1), Worksheet).Select()
wb_main.SaveAs(Filename:=_files(0)._file_path.parentDir.parentDir & "out.xlsx")
```

I get an error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC using excel 2013.  A google for the error shows alot of people with different problems as far as I can tell.

Comment: What if you replace `CType(wb_main.Worksheets(1), Worksheet)` with `DirectCast` and then `TryCast` - try. What framework you're using and 64/32 bit machine and code compilation bitness?

Comment: @T.S. that doesnt change anything as i expected.

Comment: Is there anything in event log, especially from .net runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Select()` only works on the active workbook.  `wb_main.Activate()` before selecting will solve the issue.

The second workbook open is the active one.  making edits to the workbooks by using directly assigned variables does not change the active workbook.